# How to validate in delete form

Tags: java

I'm trying to get messages in order but it seems to be something wrong, When I test to delete data that is not in database, I will get confirming message to delete that data and it will say data deleted.

```
private void deleteTeacherActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    String id = tfTeacherID.getText();

    if (Validation.textNotEmpty(tfTeacherID)) {             
        int f = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "are you sure want to delete teacher ID: "+id+"?", "Delete", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if (f==0) {             
            try {
                if (id.equals(null)) {  
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NO teacher with this ID!"); 
                }

                databas.delete("delete from teacher where teacher_id = ("+id+");");

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "teacher deleted");

            } catch(InfException ex) {  
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `id.equals(null)` was true, that'd throw a nullpointerexception... Please show what `Validation.textNotEmpty` does

Comment: @cricket_007 i added the validation class :)

Comment: Why don't you check `id.trim().isEmpty()`?

Comment: Unrelated point, but your code is susceptible to SQL injection. `where teacher_id = ("+id+");`... NEVER concatenate raw user input into sql

Comment: @cricket_007 but it works with no crashes thu ;)

Comment: It may "work", but so will a query that drops the entire database. **then** will it work? ;)

Comment: @cricket_007 this is not the solution to my problem and it has nothing to do with it ...Men and their ego hehe

Comment: So, did the trim work, or not? If not, create a [mcve] and please format your code a bit better

Comment: @cricket_007 i can't because it suppose to be with a validation class :(